# String list contains of all sub-components

Tags: c#

String list G is :

```
[0] : {"1,2,5"}
[1] : {"1,2,4,5,6"}
[2] : {"2,4,6"}
[3] : {"1,4,6"}
```

With the following commands, we conclude that `"1,4"` exists in the List G[3] :

```
if (G[i].Contains("1,4")) { //code here }
```

How to modify the above commands, that in addition feature (Contains), `"1,4"` exists in the List G[1]?

**Program codes**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < candid.Count; i++) 
    {
        foreach (TransactionTP b in transactions)
        {
            string search = candid[i];
            var searchNumbers = search.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
            for (int j = 0; j < G.Count; j++)
            {
                IEnumerable<int> numbers = G[j].Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
                int idx = 0;
                foreach (var number in numbers)
                {
                    if (number == searchNumbers[idx])
                    {
                        idx++;
                    }
                    if (idx == searchNumbers.Count)
                    {
                        arraye[i] = arraye[i] + (b.transactionUtility);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

The order of the searched term matters.

Comment: @Amin is the ordering important? For example, would the string {"4,5,1"} match?

Comment: The OP wants the contains function to be overridden such that if 1 & 4 are in the string anywhere the answer should be TRUE not the string "1,4" but more like ([^0-9]|^)[1.4]([^0-9]|$)

Comment: Is `G[n]` just a string?

Comment: PLEASE read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @Ryan S, Yes important, the array is always in order

Comment: @Evan Trimboli, yes

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve the ordering of the set you are matching go (4,1 in this case), you will need to evaluate each string, keeping track of where you are in the match.

```
string[] G = new[]
{
    "1,2,5",
    "1,2,4,5,6",
    "2,4,6",
    "1,4,6"
};

string search = "1,4";
var searchNumbers = search.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < G.Length; i++)
{
    // Convert the string into an enumeration of numbers
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = G[i].Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

    // Index to keep track of the search
    int idx = 0;

    // Loop through the input set sequentially
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        // Check if the input matches the next expected number
        if (number == searchNumbers[idx])
        {
            idx++;
        }

        if (idx == searchNumbers.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String {0} matched", G[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also must read if you have time for that => https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/

Comment: @Ryan S, I updated the question. But still received error. error is : "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.", FOR foreach `(var number in numbers)`

Comment: @CodeNotFound, Can you also help me??

Comment: @Amin the code is correct. Check this demo => https://dotnetfiddle.net/VcImUo Can you show us the content of your G array?

Comment: @CodeNotFound, G is said above, `string search` is {"1,2","1,4","2,4","2,5",...}

Comment: @Amin go to dotnetfiddle.net and put the correct sample that don't work for you and post the link into your question please.

Comment: Here is the fiddle for the code. It runs as expected. https://dotnetfiddle.net/QcHYYJ

Answer (score 1):

Replace your single Contains call with a method that does this:

```
bool passes = false;
for(int i = 0; i < G.Length; i++)
{
    List<string> temp = new List<string>();
    if(G[i].Contains(","))
    {
        temp = G[i].Split(",");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = G[i];
    }

    if(temp.Contains("1") && temp.Contains("4")
    {
        passes = true;
    }
} 

return passes;
```

This eliminates the possibility of matching on "10" or "41" etc etc
It also will not care if your elements are sorted, even though you said they are.  It will also match regardless of the number of entries between "1" and "4" in the list.

You could spice this up to take any number of inputs that you want to match before qualifying as a match, I'll leave that to you if you want to make it so.

Comment: You don't need the `if\else` for splitting you can just split and you wil get an array with one item if `,`  is not present.

Comment: 1 and 4 are an example. I want to provide a structure that searches the string array in the string list